# Describe a large integer

Tags: mathematics, english

What is the largest well-defined finite integer that you can exactly describe using unabbreviated English words (no symbols and no letters from other alphabets), with no repeated letters. Any fractions will assume to be rounded down to the nearest integer. Anything that is time-dependent is assumed to refer to the moment the answer is given. The answer does not need to be a grammatically correct sentence so long as it is clear.

By well-defined, I mean a number that can be realistically determined. E.g., 'number of cats' might be large, but can't be determined. However, 'zero' of 'my age in hours' would both be fine (though you should give the answer for the latter).

*edit* This is not a duplicate. The other question was under-constrained. In fact, I asked this because that question and the answers it got were unsatisfying.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I agree that this is not only *not a duplicate* but also an *infinitely better and more interesting question* than the one it's being compared to. I could elaborate but I'm already bored by the potential ensuing argument.

Comment: Did you mean "'zero' **or** 'my age in hours' ..."? Zero **of** an age is somewhat vague.

Comment: Please do not edit your question in a way that fundamentally change it. In particular, do not edit your question in a way that invalidates existing answers. If you'd like to ask your edited question, with the new constraint that eliminates answers that refers to other answers, ask it as a new answer.

Comment: @Gilles Surely you don't expect everyone to always foresee every possible almost-funny-the-first-time-you-see-it loophole joke. I think the asker (here and generally) has a right to disqualify boring "cheating" answers. We even have two Meta discussions about this very thing:  http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1334/the-oracle-was-lying-just-stab-them-instead-and-other-creatively-unh http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/answers-not-in-the-spirit-of-the-question

Comment: @question_asker Refering to other answers isn't a loophole here. It's explicitly allowed by the question: the question allows refering to real-world objects — and this thread is a real-world object. The meta threads you refer to are about disqualifying answers that violate explicit assumptions of the question, in particular questions being a mathematical puzzle rather than a word puzzle or situational puzzle. The question here is a word puzzle.

Comment: @Gilles Again, it's a boring exploit of an answer. It's "infinity plus one", and I can't imagine anybody accepting that were this question worded to allow repeated letters. And the meta threads are for exactly this, dunno where you got the idea they were different

Comment: @question_asker But that's the whole point! Point made by Ivan's answer and mine: the question doesn't disallow boring exploits. (A more interesting question would in fact be how you could word such a question to open it to physical and mathematical objects — which I suspect was the intent — but eliminate word tricks and self-referential tricks.)

Comment: @Gilles All I'm really saying here is that sure, go ahead and post infinity plus one, but chill out about the asker disqualifying it just because he or she didn't explicitly rule such an unclever idea out.

Comment: @Gilles I had to rule that out, otherwise there would never be an answer, just an unending stream of 'best prior answer + 1'.

Comment: @Gilles And I explicitly left the original question unchanged and added a declared edit so people would know the history of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Edit: a much larger answer.*

**Two up hymn age six**

Which I will interpret as 2, followed by (hymn age) of Knuth up-arrows, six.  The age of hymns (according to wikipedia, and we should probably go with the western variety) is roughly 2,650 [years, the default English interpretation of age], thanks to the ancient Greeks.

This gives us:

**2↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑6**

Which is less than Graham's number (in fact, less than g2, where Graham's is g64), but larger than anything else you could possibly conceive without also using up-arrow notation.

---

> Let's start this off with something decent:
>
>  **Planck time hour**
>
>  An hour in units of "Planck time" (per Wolfram Alpha) is roughly
>
>  $6.7 \times 10^{46}$
>
>  ---
>
>  Alternatively, combining two of the other ideas in here:
>
>  **Sixty Mole bang**
>
>  Which is $60(6.022141 \times 10^{23})!$, or (again, thanks Wolfram Alpha) roughly
>
>  $10^{10^{25}} = 1 \times 10^{10000000000000000000000000}$
>
>  ---
>
>  But increasingly tortured readings of English may allow us to improve this to:
>
>  **Mole sixty bang**
>
>  which is $(6.022141 \times 10^{23})!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!$, or roughly
>
>  $1 \times 10^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{10}^{{25}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}$
>
>  I'd suggest some [up-arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth's_up-arrow_notation) at this point...
>
>  $(10↑↑61)^{25}$
>
>  Of course, you might then also allow for
>
>  **Sixty Mole bang**
>
>  where the mole applies to the number of bangs.  This gets messy quickly, but a very rough estimate would be:
>
>  $10↑↑(10↑24)$

Comment: This wins it if nobody comes up with something better before a week is out. I'm playing around with 'mole' which gets us to 6.0*10^23 with letters to spare. It's unitless so really is just a number.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just a porn title? :D

Comment: Since you're not using brackets, order of operations dictates that this be interpreted as 60*[(6.02*10^23)!], which is substantially less, though still ludicrously large.

Comment: Let's see... I can't find a way around that without adding symbols, so yeah, I'll change the result.

Comment: What about "sixty up mole bang"?

Comment: Not to be picky, but isn't mole the unit itself, and the number being presented as a mole is Avogadro's Constant, a number used in the calculation of a mole?

Comment: Well, sort of.  A Mole of X is Avagadro's Number of X, so using Mole as a noun equivalent to Avagadro's Number is certainly poor grammar.  But, conveniently, we're not required to be grammatically correct - just clear and determinable.  I think Mole is good enough for those purposes.

Comment: Interestingly, sixty up mole bang = 60^[(Mole)Factorial] is only (10↑↑3)^25, while [60^(Mole)]Factorial is about (10↑↑3)^24.

Comment: What about just 60 mole bang, meaning 60!!!!!!!....!!!!! for a total of mole bangs.

Comment: Good call, though that grammar is even tougher - also, I think I crashed Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Nice. I was going to try to do something with an exbichawmp, which [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_information#Systematic_multiples) and some creative prefixing, is 18*(2^60) bits, but I don't think I'll be able to beat what you've got.

Comment: I'm not sure about this up-based answer, I don't think it's intuitive to interpret for instance, "two up five four" as 2↑↑↑↑↑4. Following order of operations it might just be (2^5)*4. Is Knuth Up Arrow notation often spoken that way?

Comment: Nah, it's exponated / pentated / etc - so, it's based on exactly how many up-arrows there are.  That said, there is no good way (to my knowledge) to pronounce an arbitrarily large up arrow value, so... presumably you'd do some variant of what I gave?  The proper grammar would probably be "two, X up arrows, six", which is actually pretty close to what I gave, and certainly within a grammatical license.

Comment: I suppose it all comes down to the minutia of what the question means by "clear". In the context of up arrows, it's fairly clear (it's the most logical interpretation anyway), but I doubt most people would go to Knuth without already knowing the context.

Answer (score 5):

**[Enormabixul](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Enormabixul)**

The Googology wiki has many like these. This one is many, many orders of magnitude greater than, for example, [Graham's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number).

**[The Rayo sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayo%27s_number)**

Rayo's number is one of the greatest numbers ever defined in mathematics. From wikipedia:

> The smallest number bigger than any finite number named by an
>   expression in the language of set theory with a googol symbols or
>   less.

Note that this definition is not [self-referential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry_paradox), since it can't be expressed using only (first-order) set theory.

A general list of googologisms can be found in the [wiki](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_googologisms).
There is also a list of [fast-growing functions](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_functions).

This may be useful for future answerers.

Answer (score 3):

**Top squared.**

Whichever answer is the top one (either [Ivan Barreto's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14219/ivan-barreto) or [Zerris's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/17389/zerris), depending on whether you consider *enormabixul* an English word — *Rayo* isn't, it's only a proper name), I'm squaring that.

Since answers are to be interpreted at the time of posting, I'm not closing the field.

Comment: ...I like it.  But there's just one problem - either your answer is the largest, or it isn't.  If it isn't the largest, we clearly shouldn't accept it as the answer to this question.  If it *is* the largest, then it is simply asking to square itself, and it provides no numeric value - ergo, it's nonsense, and it being the largest is contradictory.  Since one possibility is a contradiction and the other is not, we must be in the non-contradictory state, and this answer must not be the largest.  You could probably get around this with slightly cleverer less-direct phrasing.

Comment: @Zerris Answers are to be interpreted at the time of posting, as per the question (the question at the time I posted my answer, I mean, I notice that it's since been edited). At the time I posted my answer, my answer was not present, so it could not have been the top answer.

Comment: Ah, right you are - in which case, yes, such answers are (were) valid but inherently break the question format, since each person can respond in kind.

Answer (score 3):

**[My best](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/24471) and four**

Just to show that the list can go on.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

'MDCLXVI score bang'

Using the translation

> MDCLXVI = 1666 in Roman numerals,
>   score = 20 in 'Old' English,
>   and
>   bang = equivalent to the factorial symbol

I get $(1666 \cdot 20)! = 33320! \approx 3.1525677 \cdot10^{136225}$

Comment: I'll argue that "MDCLXVI" is not an English word.

Comment: You have a point, but I would argue that Roman Numerals have been borrowed into English in the same manner as foreign language terms such as "Pinot Noir".

Comment: For example, it is commonly used in the shorthand for a monarch' or Pope's name (Henry V for Henry the fifth, Benedict XVI etc.), and in the credits of a movie to denote the year of production (and in books to denote year of publication).

Comment: That would, however, make it *symbols* rather than *words* - equivalent to just using the numbers themselves.

Comment: I feel like the implicit multiplication is underused in this answer. If you can do that, why not "M D C L X V score bang" for (1000 * 500 * 100 * 50 * 10 * 5 * 20)!

Comment: You are using 'C' twice

Comment: So I am - that would reduce it to 1566!..

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna play off Zerris' answer and go with

**Foe Sixty Bang**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foe_(unit)

A foe is a unit of energy equal to 10^44 joules or 10^51 ergs, used to measure the large amount of energy released by a supernova.

So,

$(1 \times 10^{44})!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!$

or better yet:

$(1 \times 10^{51})!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!$ in ergs

Comment: I think unlike mole (which is a unitless number), this has a unit, so it's 1 foe unless you can say something like 'foe jules' or 'foe ergs' or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

> g sub forty k

That's $g_{40000}$, where a lowercase $g$ is Graham's sequence.

Comment: Neither g nor k are English words.

Comment: You could also say [Forcal](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Forcal), which is g sub one million, but is still much smaller than my entry, enormabixul :)

Comment: @Zerris: Only other languages' letters are disallowed by the question.

Answer (score -4):

"The largest number ever used in a serious mathematical proof."

Wich apparently isn't [Graham's Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number) anymore:

> Specific integers known to be far larger than Graham's number have since appeared in many serious mathematical proofs.

Comment: You aren't allowed to use letters more than once. And welcome to Puzzling SE.

Comment: Ah, indeed. Overlooked that detail. Too bad even "Graham's Number" has duplicate letters...